# How to get variable ID from php to jquery

Tags: jquery

This is me first question ever. I looking solution one week, and although I tried many ways, still doesn't work.

I don't know how from php get variable ID to jquery; below me short code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    var ID = $(this).attr('id');   //here I would like to get <?php echo $id; ?>

        $('#itemCode_'+ ID ).autocomplete({
            source: 'data/item-data.php',
            minLength: 1,
            select: function(event, ui) {

var ID = $(this).attr('id');

    $(this).closest('tr').find('#itemCode_' + ID).val(ui.item.itemCode);    
    $(this).closest('tr').find('#itemDut').val(ui.item.itemDut);
    $(this).closest('tr').find('#itemDesc').val(ui.item.itemDesc);

       $('#itemQty').focus();

      return false;   }
```

Below is my php which is multiplicate by loom while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))

```
<tr class="item-row">
<td><input id="itemCode_<?php echo $id; ?>" name="itemCode[]" class="itemCode" value="<?php echo $part_nr;?>"  ></td>
<td><input name="itemDut[]" value="<?php  echo $itemDut;?>"  ></td>
<td><input name="itemDesc[]" value="<?php  echo $forecast;?>"  ></td>
</tr>
```

Please help me find solution, but really I'm stuck. I'd like to add that I also try use . class.

Comment: This has been asked [many, many times before](https://www.google.com/search?q=variable+from+php+to+jquery+site%3Astackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 0):

```
var ID = $('.itemCode').prop('id').split('_')[1];
```

Get the only item with the `itemCode` class. Gets its ID (itemCode_ID). Split on `_`. Get the second part; the ID.

Comment: I already tried use class instead id and with _ and without _. But without success :|

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have multiple rows that need an autcomplete, you can simplify this by adding a common class to each of the various inputs

```
<td><input class="itemCode" id="itemCode_<?php echo $id; ?>" name="itemCode[]" value="<?php echo $part_nr;?>"  ></td>
<td><input class="itemDut" name="itemDut[]" value="<?php  echo $itemDut;?>"  ></td>
<td><input class="itemDesc" name="itemDesc[]" value="<?php  echo $forecast;?>"  ></td>
```

Now call autocomplete for the whole class of `itemCode` and search for the corresonding classes within the select event.

ID's are not needed to make this traversal or to call the autocomplete initialization:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.itemCode').autocomplete({
        source: 'data/item-data.php',
        minLength: 1,
        select: function(event, ui) {


            $(this).closest('tr').find('.itemCode').val(ui.item.itemCode);
            $(this).closest('tr').find('.itemDut').val(ui.item.itemDut);
            $(this).closest('tr').find('.itemDesc').val(ui.item.itemDesc);

            $('#itemQty').focus();

            return false;
        }
    })
  })
```

Comment: Works only first item. Next show only that something happen but don't wont to show value from autocomplete. (Table and input are multiplied via loom while selected from database)

Comment: not sure why , should work for all. Give me a sample of JSON data will create a demo

Comment: mysql_select_db($dbname);

    $return_arr = array();
    $param = $_GET["term"];
    $fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE itemCode REGEXP '^$param' LIMIT 5");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
 
        $row_array['id']  = $row['id'];
        $row_array['itemCode'] = $row['itemCode'];
        $row_array['itemDesc'] = $row['itemDesc'];
        $row_array['itemPrice'] = $row['itemPrice'];

        array_push( $return_arr, $row_array );
    }
    mysql_close($conn);
    echo json_encode($return_arr);

Comment: list menu output of the autocomplete
    }).data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append( "<a>" + item.itemCode + " - " + item.itemDesc +  "</a>" )
            .appendTo( ul );
    };

Comment: that is not JSON data that gets sent to page from `echo json_encode($return_arr);`

Comment: [{"itemDut":"","itemCode":"100122","itemDesc":"Search Engine Optimization","itemQty":"","Unit":"0","itemPrice":"50.3","Manufacturer":"","itemStock":"0"},{"itemDut":"","itemCode":"10033","itemDesc":"Logo Development","itemQty":"","Unit":"0","itemPrice":"300","Manufacturer":"","itemStock":"0"},{"itemDut":"","itemCode":"1004","itemDesc":"Design Consulting","itemQty":"","Unit":"0","itemPrice":"150.99","Manufacturer":"","itemStock":"0"},{"itemDut":"","itemCode":"551003","itemDesc":"Logo Development","itemQty":"6","Unit":"0","itemPrice":"300","Manufacturer":"","itemStock":"0"}]

Comment: OK... I made working demo with simplified data...can see it work for all rows ...link above

Comment: its work like you said, problem begin where I put var data = 'data/data.php';

Comment: Many thanks charlietfl, you help me, your solutions works perfectly!